# PCA : How to get the sum of variance table and a graph in Pyspark python

Tags: python, pyspark, pca

I am performing PCA in Pyspark and the below code gives me the sum of variance for k = 12 reuced dimensions

```
#Dimension reduction using PCA
pca = PCA(k=17, inputCol = scaler.getOutputCol(), outputCol="pcaFeatures")
model = pca.fit(Product_score_data_scaled)

PCA_transformed_feature = model.transform(Product_score_data_scaled)

#Sum of Variance explained
np.round(100.00*model.explainedVariance.toArray(),4).sum()
```

I have 200 features in original data. How can I get a table which has sum of variance for k = 1 till K = 200 and also plot it into a graph to select the best k in pyspark?

I tried the below to create a table. but it takes too much time

```
PC_count = []
variance = []
for k in range(1, len(cols_to_scale)):
  pca = PCA(k= k, inputCol = scaler.getOutputCol(), outputCol="pcaFeatures")
  model = pca.fit(Product_score_data_scaled)
  variance.append(np.round(100.00*model.explainedVariance.toArray(),4).sum())
  PC_count.append(k)
```

Comment: is it k=12 or k=17 ?

Comment: Its 'Twelve' k = 12

Comment: but in your code, there is no 12 ...

Comment: @Steve, sorry it's 17. But the purpose of my needed code is take all values of  k from 1 to 200 and create a spark table. The first column will have value of k and the second column will have value of 'sum_of_variance'.

Comment: Sure but if I don't understand what to change, that's difficult to find an answer

Comment: I understand @Steven. Hope now it's clear.

Comment: is this the same as what you are asking? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63190529/how-to-determine-the-optimum-number-of-features-in-pca-with-pyspark